# Nested loop Running Time?

Tags: algorithm, big-o, asymptotic-complexity

What is Running Time in Big oh notation of:

```
for(int i=1;i<N;i++)

    for(int j=1;j<N;j*=2)
```

The loop will stop when j > N. If we let k be some arbitrary iteration of the loop, the value of j on iteration k will be 2k. The loop stops when 2k > n, which happens when k > log2 n.

Therefore, the number of iterations is only O(log n), so the total complexity is O(log n).

Is this correct?

Comment: Just FYI - your posts are being discussed on Meta.SO: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/323749/607407

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `O(n)` for the outer loop and `O(log(n))` for the inner one. So the total is `O(n*log(n))`.